# Unable to download XLSX file using Curl or Wget on UNIX

Tags: unix, curl, wget, xlsx

Could anyone please help. I am trying to download a XLSX file using curl/wget from UNIX. I have already tried searching through the similar issues other users were facing but nothing helped so far.

Every Time it downloads a login page html only even after specifying the username and password explicitly. I am able to download without any issues from the browser.

Have tried these options where url is  - http://www.dtcc.com/log-in-center?media=/~/media/Download-Center/Insurance/cusip/production_cusip.xlsx

curl -v -u username:pass -O url

curl  -v -d "username=xxx&password=yyyy&submit=Login" -O url

curl -v -u user:pass -A "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0" -O url

Comment: check how the browser is trying to log in. they have a bunch of parameters, presumably to protect against XSS and the like, which must match, for a sucessfull login. furthermore, i suspect you cant download it in 1 go, first you must get a cookie session and the login parameters (called __VIEWSTATE / __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR / __EVENTVALIDATION / etc), then login, then use the cookie session which is already logged in, and download with that. this goes beyond what you can do in a simple command, you need a script to download this from cli (php would be a good fit). got an actual account to test?

Comment: Thanks hanshenrik. Going to try. Would let you know if it succeeds. Yes I have an actual account but wont be able to share it (its official ;))

Comment: @hanshenrik - I can see from the login page that name of the form fields username and password are mentioned like this -  <input name="main_1$txtUser" type="text" id="main_1_txtUser" placeholder="user name" />    <input name="main_1$txtPassword" type="password" id="main_1_txtPassword" title="password" class="txtPassword" />                                 So I am trying to post the form data using these commands -                 curl -v -c cookies.txt -X POST -F 'main_1$txtUser=user;type=text' -X POST -F 'main_1$txtPassword=pass;type=password' url
curl -v -b cookies.txt -O url. Still nt wrkg

Comment: yeah. you need more than curl.  First, you must make a call do the login page. then you get a cookie session, and a VIEWSTATE id and stuff. then (and this is the part curl cannot do itself, you need a script to do this part) you need to parse the html, parse out the __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION and ctl09$header_0$search_box_text, and when you've parsed out those values from the HTML, you need to make a second request, this time a POST request, with those values, and a value called main_1$txtUser  for the username, and main_1$txtPassword  for the password, and more